# How to build Framework from Static library in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries

I have .a files of all Architecture i.e. arm64, armv7,armv7s.

Now i want to build a Framework from all static library how to do that? now i have  Universal .a file and headers how to convert into framework?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_SQ8zw0Sq0&t=72s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A static framework on iOS is basically a folder structure.

You could use command line tools (basically a script) to "create" the folder structure suitable for a framework after xCode has finished compiling the Library.

You would need to add "Run Script Build Phase" and add all the necessary commands.

Have a look at this tutorial:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios